# How to end my for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to end a for loop in Javascript.. obvious answer is while loop - however I'm not sure how to implement it here, I tried putting while on the front of the for loop (while(stop==false)), but then it lasts forever...

The function this code is in is performed every 1 millisecond. At the moment, even if stop == true it goes through the rest of the divs.. How do I make it that if stop == true, don't carry on looking through them.

```
<script>
    for (var i = 1; i <= gDivCount; i++) {

        var topleftofgdiv = [$("#" + i).position().top, $("#" + i).position().left];
        var toprightofgdiv = [$("#" + i).position().top,
        $("#" + i).position().left + $("#" + i).width()];

        if (topleftofgdiv[0] > bottomleft[0]) {
            var stop = false;
            console.log(false);
        } else {
            var stop = true;
            console.log(true);
        }

        if (stop == false) {
            var pandanewpos = $("#moveDiv").position().top + 3;
            document.getElementById("moveDiv").style.top = pandanewpos + "px";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding `break;` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break):

```
if(stop){
    break;
}
```

For simplicity, you can use your existing `if` statement:

```
if (stop == false) {
    var pandanewpos...
}
else {
    break;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Made my life so much easier - will accept as right answer as soon as it lets me :)

Comment: `if(stop == true)` seriously